# regarding menubar to show icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I want to display an icon on the menubar.Iam creating menubar using dojo.
Please find the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/351/

I tried uisng icon attribute to display icon on menu bar, but it did not worked.
Below is the sample code:

```
require([
    "dijit/MenuBar",
    "dijit/PopupMenuBarItem",
    "dijit/Menu",
    "dijit/MenuItem",
    "dijit/DropDownMenu",
    "dijit/PopupMenuItem",
    "dojo/domReady!"
],function(MenuBar, PopupMenuBarItem, Menu, MenuItem, DropDownMenu,PopupMenuItem){
    var pMenuBar = new MenuBar({
     });


   var pSubMenu = new DropDownMenu({});
    pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "File item #1"
    }));
    pSubMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "File item #2"
    }));

    pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
        label : "Home",
       icon: 'https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16',
        popup: pSubMenu
    }));

    var withdrawMenu = new Menu({
                id: "withdrawMenu"
            });
    withdrawMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
                id: "savings",
                label: "Savings Acc"
            }) );
    withdrawMenu.addChild(new MenuItem({
                id: "checking",
                label: "Checking Acc"
            }) );

    var pSubMenu2 = new DropDownMenu({});
    pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Credit"
    }));

     pSubMenu2.addChild(new PopupMenuItem({
                id: "withdraw",
                label: "Withdraw",
                popup: withdrawMenu
            }) );

    pSubMenu2.addChild(new MenuItem({
        label: "Retail"
    }));  

    pMenuBar.addChild(new PopupMenuBarItem({
        label: " || Banking",
        popup: pSubMenu2
    }));

    pMenuBar.placeAt("menuBar");
    pMenuBar.startup();
});
```

Please suggest how to show icon on the menu item instead of showing label.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this with `dijit/PopupMenubarItem` as per the doc. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/MenuBar.html#icons

An alternative is to use [dijit/ToolBar](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Toolbar.html#dijit-toolbar) with corresponding dropdownbuttons

Also to use the icon you need to use the
**iconClass** property and add a CSS style to the document.
e.g

In the javascript file.

```
new MenuItem({
        label: "File item #1",
        iconClass:'myIcon'
    }
```

In the CSS file or style tag add the following css.

```
.myIcon {
            background-image: url("https://avatars1.githubusercontent.com/u/5500999?v=2&s=16");
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
        }
```

**Edit1:**

As stated above you need to use combination of [dijit/ToolBar](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Toolbar.html#dijit-toolbar), dijit/DropDownMenu, and [dijit/form/DropDownButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html). check out the links.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html

Comment: Thanks @frank. But can we achieve the same kind of dropdown menu's as shown in  http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/351/ when we use dijit/ToolBar with corresponding dropdownbuttons . ANy suggestions would be helpful. Thanks.